# OnsenUI all ons.* functions doesn't work

Tags: onsen-ui

I'm started to use OnsenUI with Angular.

In some patterns ons. functions are used (like `ons.bootstrap()` ).

But in my case, it doesn't work.

My navigator error consol is like this `ReferenceError: ons is not defined`

If someone have some idea to fix my problem it will be great :)

Thanks

**Just for information :** It was just because i was not up to date with onsen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you included `angular.js` and `onsenui.js` before calling the method?

For example if you're using a CDN you can do:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.2.2/build/js/onsenui.min.js"></script>
<script>
  ons.bootstrap();
</script>
```

If you do this do you still get the same error? Are you using IE?

Comment: If i use just your code, it's working. But not in mine xD Thanks you, my problem is solved. I will try to fix it in my project now :)

Comment: I fix it ! I was using an old version of OnsenUI (1.0.4) and now it's 1.2.2 ! Thanks you for your help :)